# CCP site-to-site VPN using access rules

Tags: vpn, cisco, site-to-site-vpn

I use CCP for creating site-to-site VPNs on a Cisco router. I need to use network objects on my ipsec rule for having multiple hosts but the network objects are only available on the access rules through access editor.

On the encryption domain dialogue on site-to-site VPN wizzard the access rules I have created from Access Editor window are not listed. Should I associate the rules with the interface to be listed???

I manage to create a VPN using an access rule by just inserting the access rule (that is not associated to any interface) number, - it wasn't listed on the access rules when I clicked select from the existing rules - the VPN worked but then another issue came up.

The issue is that when I created a second VPN the way I described above the public IP of the router is unreachable. No ping/ssh etc. I recover it by shh on private and reload with the old config. While the public interface seems down the VPNs I have already configured are up and running.

Though the router is going down when a new s-to-s VPN is created by using an access rule if I create a VPN with the way is shown on the image below everything works fine.

http://www.cisco.com/image/gif/paws/112153/ccp-vpn-asa-router-config-24.gif

but with that way I cannot have multiple hosts for my VPN.

Comment: vitotol, welcome to Server Fault! Could you please state your question **more clearly**? What are you asking for?

Comment: sorry for if I confused you. I am using Cisco Configuration professional for managing VPNs. I wanted to create VPNs with many hosts on the encryptio domains so I created many access rules with network objects so i can associate those with the IPsec rules

that way I messed up the access rules and the firewall.

instead of this way i was created many ipsec rules for each vpn, that way it worked and i had no issues.